# How to display invisible div with contents of just-filled input field with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword1" placeholder="Keyword #1 "><br>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">one two</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="keyword2" placeholder="Keyword #2 "><br>
        </div>
        <div class="help-block">one two</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

on page load, help-blocks are hidden via jquery. I want them shown soon after someone fills in the input for each one. They should display with the text entered.

Here's the jquery I'm trying to improve:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //hide the boxes where results will be shown
        $('.help-block').hide();

        $('input:text').blur(function (){
            $(this).next().val(this.val());
        });

    });

</script>
```

Needless to say i'm still finding my feet with jquery, any pointers?

Comment: Why are you hiding them up-front with jQuery? Seems unnecessary since you could just hide them with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems

1. Use `$(this).val()` instead of `this.val()`
2. `help-block` div is sibling of input's parent
3. If you need to display them use `.show()`

Use

```
$('input:text').blur(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().siblings('.help-block').html($(this).val()).show();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DHepN/)

Comment: Question, why do you have to set preventDefault? Also, i'm I right in assuming "event" parameter automatically represents "this"?

Comment: @Chiko, You can remove `event.preventDefault();` and **event !== this**, *this is object which invoked the event*